# nginx proxy URl failing

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I wanted to host a Nginx proxy infront of a private network, where all the private client users can talk to a specific URL through the proxy server. But once it connect the URL  there is an authentication redirection is happening and that time URl got changed and since my private network doesn't  have any way to connect other URL[ internet is blocked] its is getting timeout. can anybody please share some thoughts to fix this?

I have pasted my config below

```
server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
        server_name    k8s.cluster.mstsg.com;
        ssl_certificate /var/tmp/omni/fullchain.pem ;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/tmp/omni/privkey.pem ;
        ssl_ciphers         EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;
        ssl_protocols        TLSv1.2;
        error_log    error.log debug;




        location /{
           proxy_pass https://ms-tsg.cp.cloud;
           proxy_ssl_server_name on;
           proxy_set_header Host ms-tsg.cp.cloud;
           proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        }
```

a) client will hit the url k8s.cluster.mstsg.com which  is the proxy server
b) then it will be forwarded to "https://ms-tsg.cp.cloud" and then it is redirected to another URL "https://auth-tsg.cp.cloud" for authentication.
c) browser will fail  during authentication redirection, reason is my client has access only  to proxy and when the URL changed in the header then it is getting time out.

can any body share some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical problem with proxying. What you want is overriding the return urls while proxying

```
location /{
   proxy_pass https://ms-tsg.cp.cloud;
   proxy_ssl_server_name on;
   proxy_set_header Host ms-tsg.cp.cloud;
   proxy_redirect https://auth-tsg.cp.cloud https://k8s2.cluster.mstsg.com
   proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

Then you will need to create one more virtual server with `server_name` as `k8s2.cluster.mstsg.com` and then `proxy_pass` it to `auth-tsg.cp.cloud`

Comment: Thanks Tarun. I have made the provided changes and now i see timeout on https://ms-tsg.cp.cloud. To override the URL I added https://ms-tsg.cp.cloud in the proxy_redirect and after that i was not able to start nginx. Please see the config i added.

error i got in nginx log
====

 invalid number of arguments in "proxy_redirect" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reverse-proxy.conf:17
 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
=====
Can  you please share your thoughts

Comment: location /{
       proxy_pass https://ms-tsg.cp.cloud;
       proxy_redirect https://auth-tsg.cp.cloud https://k8s2.cluster.mstsg.com https://ms-tsg.cp.cloud;
       proxy_set_header Host ms-tsg.cp.cloud;
       proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }

Comment: `proxy_redirect` redirect takes two parameters. `proxy_redirect <searchtext> <replacementtext>`, if you need multiple replacements use multiple `proxy_redirect` directives. Once you correct that mistake it should work

Comment: Thanks. now its loading, but now its too many redirect error. "k8s.cluster.mstsg.com" redirected  too many times.                                            
    Do we need to add any additional config on the proxy pass directive?

Comment: You need to have `proxy_redirect  https://auth-tsg.cp.cloud https://k8sauth.cluster.mstsg.com` and use `k8sauth.cluster.mstsg.com` in the other server block, because you need a way to separate between the two host names

Comment: is that what  you told me?                                                                                                          https://pastebin.com/pknTbtn6

Comment: See this https://pastebin.com/mLtiWFzv, you need different server names

Comment: I didn't define this name " k8sauth.cluster.mstsg.com" anywhere in my application, so simply adding  this server_name  in nginx config will work?

Comment: you need to make sure the dns for same points to ip of `k8s.cluster.mstsg.com`

Comment: sorry to ask you again. even after adding DNS mapped to k8s.cluster.mstsg.com, how nginx will distinguish the URL should redirect to  proxy_redirect https://auth-tsg.cp.cloud?. I didn't define "k8s.cluster.mstsg.com" in where in my application or  the URL am connecting initially?. correct me if am wrong.

Comment: You have virtual host for both of them and you are rewriting one server to another during the `proxy_redirect`. That's how it works

Comment: I have added the "k8sauth.cluster.mstsg.com" DNS as a CNAME entry. also added the new "k8sauth.cluster.mstsg.com" name in my certificate as a SAN name. can you check final config looks good https://pastebin.com/2gsJMcat.                               i tried with this and now am getting the same timeout for the auth URL i got initially.

Comment: Looks fine, you will have to debug I guess why it's not working